# Returning an Iterator<String> from String[]

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a class `foo` with a field `String[] bar`. I want `foo` to implement `Iterable<String>`.

So I'm writing

```
@Override            
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    // ToDo - return some function of `bar`
}
```

What can I put in the line marked `ToDo` to make an `Iterator` out of `bar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with:

```
return Arrays.asList(bar).iterator();
```